# Hiding fetch quest map markers

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Is there a way to hide all of the "fetch" or "collection" quest map markers?

Once you spot a Shard on the map, the map marker will continue to appear. Is there a way to hide all of them?

[image]

You can see here that there are many map markers that show the locations of shards and whatever and once you get a lot of them showing at once, it can really clutter the map even when you have another quest marked as the active one.

Comment: I don`t think you can hide them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no plug in or add on that hides these map markers and there is no way to do this in game. I will update my answer if I ever come across a way to do so.